# Apagar valor de sessão de uma variável

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho um botão *reset* para apagar valores de um formulário.

Acontece que queria apagar a variável de sessão no PHP e não consigo fazer, pode ser por jQuery.

É este código que tenho:

```
document.getElementById("pesquisa").reset();
```

Answer (score 1):

Cria uma função que chamara o *reset* que você usa atualmente e limpará a *session* através do Ajax, bastará apensas chamara a função no botão onde o `type` será `Button` e o `onclick` você passa o nome da função criada.

Código PHP:

```
Try {
    // limpa a sessão
    $_SESSION = array();

    // destroy a sessão
    session_destroy();

    echo "sucesso";
}
cacth(Exception $e) {
    echo "erro";
}
```

Código jQuery:

```
function resetSession() {
    $("pesquisa").reset();

    $.ajax({
        url: "Acao.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {},
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != "sucesso") {
                Alert("Session não finalizada!");
            }
            else {
                Alert("Session finalizada!");
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            Alert("Ocorreu uma falha!";
        }
    });
}
```